# charter package: broken umlauts with fontenc package and T1 encoding

Tags: font-encodings, german

I want to use the `fontenc` package in combination with the `charter` font package (using `pdflatex` for compiling). With `\usepackage[TI]{fontenc}` included, however, the capital versions of german umlauts aren't rendered correctly anymore. Is there a way to fix this or are the two packages incompatible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\begin{document}
Ü Ä Ö
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit:

Using `\showoutput` with the `acticle` class as requested in the comments yields the following:

```
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 539.94232fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 1.01001
...\hbox(8.98999+0.14)x345.0, glue set 303.8fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\T1/bch/m/n/10 Ü
....\glue 2.78 plus 1.66832 minus 0.67065
....\T1/bch/m/n/10 Ä
....\glue 2.78 plus 1.66832 minus 0.67065
....\T1/bch/m/n/10 Ö
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue -0.14
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.175
..\hbox(6.825+0.0)x345.0, glue set 169.72fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\T1/bch/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil


{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
(/compile/output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 633 strings out of 480906
 8851 string characters out of 5908280
 242476 words of memory out of 5000000
 16294 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 538673 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,25p,150b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base
/8r.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchr8a
.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 10738 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the output: I get the [expected output (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXmev.png) Can you please change `standalone` into `article` and add `\showoutput` just before `\end{document}` and report the contents of the log file from `Completed box being shipped out`?

Comment: Hmm, which distribution are you using? I tested it both locally (using TeX Live) and on Overleaf (which is where I created the screenshot) and got the same result on both.

Comment: You might also try `XCharter`.

Comment: Using XCharter actually solved the problem, thank you!